# Can we extend an injective analytic function to a holomorphic *injective* function?

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume $ \gamma:\left(a,b\right)\to\mathbb{C} $ is an injective analytic path with $ \gamma'(t) \neq 0 $ for any  $ t \in (a,b) $. Is it true that $ \gamma $ can be extended to an injective holomprhic function on some neighbourhood of $ (a,b) $ in $ \mathbb{C} $ ?

It is obvious that $ \gamma $ can be extended to a holomorphic function of some union of disks. But can it be extended to an injective holomorphic function somewhere ?

Im not sure if the answer is true or false, but I couldnt find a counter example and couldnt prove it either. So any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a compact interval and then result true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No try with $\gamma(x)=e^{ix}(e^{ix}-1)$ its derivative is non-zero and it has a self-intersection at $\pm \pi/3$ so that $(a,b)=(-\pi/3,\pi/2)$ gives a counter-example. The image of the analytic continuation to a neighborhood of $\pi/3$ contains $\gamma(-\pi/3+\epsilon)$.

[image]

Comment: dont we need the image to contain $ \gamma\left(-\frac{\pi}{3}\right) $ in order to conclude that the analytic coninuation is not injective?